# d3js flicker on transform with text inside g

Tags: d3.js

i have the following https://jsfiddle.net/zzxpw3o0/

```
function dragstart(d) {
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}
```

when dragging the circle i get strange flicker

If i remove the g wrapping the circle and the text all is good.

https://jsfiddle.net/e2t2z8uj/

Wondering if i can fix the flicker. I have around 1k circles with text label , so i don't want to create 2k svg:g for circle + text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move your call to the `force.drag` function from the circles to the group, like so:

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.values(nodes))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .call(force.drag); // <= move that line here

nodes.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function (d, i) { return colors(i); })
    // .call(force.drag); // <= remove this line
```

The updated fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gleezer/zg5vjzs4/).

Comment: great thanks, but can you explain why? i used your solution to fix this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-template-jq8khd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts